# How to split a column which has multiple dots using Linux command line

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file which looks like this:

`chr10:100013403..100013414,-    0       0       0       0
chr10:100027943..100027958,-    0       0       0       0
chr10:100076685..100076699,+    0       0       0       0`

I want output to be like:

`chr10    100013403    100013414    -    0       0       0       0
chr10    100027943    100027958    -    0       0       0       0
chr10    100076685    100076699    +    0       0       0       0`

So, I want the first column to be tab separated at field delimiter = :  ,  ..
I have used `awk -F":|," '$1=$1' OFS="\t" file` to separate first column. But, I am still struggling with `..` characters.
I tried `awk -F":|,|.." '$1=$1' OFS="\t" file` but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`..` should be escaped.

```
awk -F':|,|\\.\\.' '$1=$1' OFS="\t" file
```

> It is important to remember that when you assign a string constant as the value of FS, it undergoes normal awk string processing. For example, with Unix awk and gawk, the assignment `FS = "\.."` assigns the character string `..` to FS (the backslash is stripped). This creates a regexp meaning “fields are separated by occurrences of any two characters.” If instead you want fields to be separated by a literal period followed by any single character, use `FS = "\\.."`.

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Splitting-Summary.html

Comment: Yes, John. That is what I was trying but didn't work. Any comment @haolee?

Comment: @John1024 Oh, I make a mistake. You are right! Both periods should be escaped because`\\..` means "a literal period followed by any single character" while `\\.\\.` means "two literal periods". `\\..` can split `123.a123` to `123 123` while `\\.\\.` don't split this string. If the input string is `123..123`, these two field separators lead to the same result. Thanks for your correction! The answer has been updated. @Shubham Gupta

Comment: @haolee Excellent. +1.

Answer (score 0):

If your Input_file is same as shown sample then following may help you too in same.

```
awk '{gsub(/:|\.+|\,/,"\t");} 1'   Input_file
```

Here I am using gsub keyword of awk to globally substitute (:) (.+ which will take all dots) (,) with TAB and then 1 will print the edited/non-edited line of Input_file. I hope this helps.